# parse_signed_request - base64_url_decode - strstr use

Tags: php, facebook, base64

in the facebook php reference there the 
parse_signed_request to check out a signed_request
I don't understand the use of
`strtr($input, '-_', '+/')` in

```
function base64_url_decode($input) {
   return base64_decode(strtr($input, '-_', '+/'));
}
```

I've echoed the `$input` string but at least
in my case there is no '`-_`' to replace with '`+/`'
Can you explain what's it for ?
Bye.

Answer (score 3):

The function is not replacing `-_` with `+/` but rather `-` with `+` and `_` with `/`. The reason for doing this is, that base64-encoded strings may contain characters which are not safe for URLs. Take a look at this [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#URL_applications) for details.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like regular expressions, to replace an underscore (_) with a forward slash (/).

Comment: I agree but [I've echoed the $input string but at least in my case there is no '-_' to replace with '+/'] so I'm wondering why ?

Comment: Probably something that doesn't get used often, or are there just in case it is needed